# How do I convert/change an activity into a fragment?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-activity

I am an extreme-beginner android app developer and I coded a few portions of the app as activities, whereas they should be fragments. Below I have the code for one of my question classes and its coordinating layout file. What specifically do I change here to make it a fragment. Also, wherever I am starting a new activity, I will actually be going to a new fragment.

```
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.Toast;

        public class VehicleActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
            private ImageButton car, bike, motor, bus, walk, truck;
            public String vehicleType;
            @Override
            protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                setContentView(R.layout.activity_vehicle);

                vehicleID(); //sets id for each button
                onClickListeners(); //a method which sets on click listeners and listens for clicks

                ImageButton b = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.info);
                b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        startActivity(new Intent(VehicleActivity.this, VehiclePop.class));
                    }
                });        


            }

            public void vehicleID()
            {
                car = findViewById(R.id.carImage);
                bike = findViewById(R.id.bikeImage);
                motor = findViewById(R.id.motorImage);
                bus = findViewById(R.id.busImage);
                walk = findViewById(R.id.walkImage);
                truck = findViewById(R.id.truckImage);
            }

            public void onClickListeners()
            {
                car.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                      vehicleType="Car"  ;
                      toaster();
                      nextQ();
                    }
                });
                bike.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        vehicleType="Bicycle"  ;
                        toaster();
                        nextQ();
                    }
                });
                motor.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                vehicleType="Motorcycle/Mo-ped"  ;
                toaster();
                nextQ();
            }
        });
        bus.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                vehicleType="Bus"  ;
                toaster();
                nextQ();
            }
        });
        truck.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                vehicleType="Truck"  ;
                toaster();
                nextQ();
            }
        });
        walk.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                vehicleType="Walk"  ;
                toaster();
                nextQ();
            }
        });
    }

    public void nextQ() //this method is used to go to the next screen
    {

        Intent intent = new Intent(this, DrivingDistActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }

    public void toaster() //create and show a toast
    {
        Toast.makeText(VehicleActivity.this, "Vehicle Type: " + vehicleType, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }
}
```

Here is the XML layout for the corresponding class.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:weightSum="10"
    android:background="@drawable/blueback"
    tools:context=".VehicleActivity">


    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="2">


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textGrid"
            android:layout_width="320dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:text="Which mode of transport of you use most frequently?"
            android:textColor="@color/colorWhite"
            android:textSize="25sp"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal" />



    </RelativeLayout>

    <GridLayout
        android:columnCount="2"
        android:rowCount="3"
        android:layout_weight="8"
        android:alignmentMode="alignMargins"
        android:columnOrderPreserved="false"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:padding="14dp">

        <!--Row 1-->
        <!--Column 1-->
        <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView

            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:layout_rowWeight="1"
            android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
            app:cardElevation="8dp"
            app:cardCornerRadius="8dp">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
                android:layout_margin="16dp"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <ImageButton
                    android:id="@+id/carImage"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:src="@drawable/greencar"
                    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                    android:scaleType="centerInside"
                    android:background = "@drawable/clearroundedbutton"/>

            </LinearLayout>

        </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
        <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView

            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:layout_rowWeight="1"
            android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
            app:cardElevation="8dp"
            app:cardCornerRadius="8dp">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
                android:layout_margin="16dp"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <ImageButton
                    android:id="@+id/bikeImage"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:src="@drawable/bike"
                    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                    android:scaleType="centerInside"
                    android:background = "@drawable/clearroundedbutton"/>

            </LinearLayout>

        </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
        <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView

            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:layout_rowWeight="1"
            android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
            app:cardElevation="8dp"
            app:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
            >

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
                android:layout_margin="16dp"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <ImageButton
                    android:id="@+id/motorImage"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:src="@drawable/motorcycle"
                    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                    android:scaleType="centerInside"
                    android:background = "@drawable/clearroundedbutton"/>

            </LinearLayout>

        </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
        <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView

            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:layout_rowWeight="1"
            android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
            app:cardElevation="8dp"
            app:cardCornerRadius="8dp">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
                android:layout_margin="16dp"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <ImageButton
                    android:id="@+id/busImage"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:src="@drawable/bus"
                    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                    android:scaleType="centerInside"
                    android:background = "@drawable/clearroundedbutton"/>

            </LinearLayout>

        </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
        <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView

            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:layout_rowWeight="1"
            android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
            app:cardElevation="8dp"
            app:cardCornerRadius="8dp">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
                android:layout_margin="16dp"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <ImageButton
                    android:id="@+id/walkImage"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:src="@drawable/mountain"
                    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                    android:scaleType="centerInside"
                    android:background = "@drawable/clearroundedbutton"/>

            </LinearLayout>

        </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
        <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView

            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:layout_rowWeight="1"
            android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
            app:cardElevation="8dp"
            app:cardCornerRadius="8dp">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
                android:layout_margin="16dp"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <ImageButton
                    android:id="@+id/truckImage"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:src="@drawable/truck"
                    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                    android:scaleType="centerInside"
                    android:background = "@drawable/clearroundedbutton"/>

            </LinearLayout>

        </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>



    </GridLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="30dp">

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/info"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_info"
            tools:ignore="VectorDrawableCompat"
            android:background="#00000000"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"/>

    </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To create a fragment simply inflate the layout.xml inside onCreateView() and map the views (findviewbyid) and other initializations inside onViewCreated().
Here is the code have a look:-

```
public class VehicleActivity extends Fragment {
        private ImageButton car, bike, motor, bus, walk, truck;
        public String vehicleType;

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_vehicle,container,false);

}

@Override
public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
    ImageButton b = (ImageButton) view.findViewById(R.id.info);
    vehicleID(); //sets id for each button
    onClickListeners(); //a method which sets on click listeners and listens for 
    clicks
    b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            startActivity(new Intent(getActivity(), VehiclePop.class));
        }
    });
}


        public void vehicleID()
        {
            car = getView().findViewById(R.id.carImage);
            bike = getView().findViewById(R.id.bikeImage);
            motor = getView().findViewById(R.id.motorImage);
            bus = getView().findViewById(R.id.busImage);
            walk = getView().findViewById(R.id.walkImage);
            truck = getView().findViewById(R.id.truckImage);
        }

        public void onClickListeners()
        {
            car.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                  vehicleType="Car"  ;
                  toaster();
                  nextQ();
                }
            });
            bike.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    vehicleType="Bicycle"  ;
                    toaster();
                    nextQ();
                }
            });
            motor.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            vehicleType="Motorcycle/Mo-ped"  ;
            toaster();
            nextQ();
        }
    });
    bus.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            vehicleType="Bus"  ;
            toaster();
            nextQ();
        }
    });
    truck.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            vehicleType="Truck"  ;
            toaster();
            nextQ();
        }
    });
    walk.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            vehicleType="Walk"  ;
            toaster();
            nextQ();
        }
    });
}

public void nextQ() //this method is used to go to the next screen
{

    Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), DrivingDistActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}

public void toaster() //create and show a toast
{
    Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Vehicle Type: " + vehicleType, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

}
}
```

Comment: One question, dont we need a Container to "inflate " the fragments. If so, how would I implement this

Comment: I have edited the answer there was a mistake in onCreateView(), I have fixed it added the container have a look.

Comment: One more question. If I have to open this fragment from a button on an activity, how would I do that, do you need the code for this to answer?

Comment: Refer to this developer guide:-
https://guides.codepath.com/android/creating-and-using-fragments